# jquery droppable not receiving divs from sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to ask for you help with a problem i have with a sortable and a droppable witj jquery-ui.

I want to have a div (source) where i have lots of items groups by categories (to make it easier to read). The categories are all sortable. I want to be able to move from items from here to a droppable div.It seems like nothing happens when i drop the item as you may see in :  http://jsfiddle.net/eUzeu/2/.

The funny thing is that if i echo (alert) **$(dropped).attr('id')** in the drop function it actually shows the correct div. But for some weird reason seems like it's triggering but the div doesn't gets attached to the droppable.

Any idea ?

I read that it seems that the connectWith allows to connect sortable with droppables but as you may see seems like it'snot working.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `connectWith` is a little communitarian and only works between sortables. Would replacing your droppable with a sortable be a problem? [It might achieve what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/eUzeu/3/).

Comment: I hate you ! i've been dealing with this for hours and you fix it in a couple of seconds !!! thanks a lot man, you saved my day :)  I just want to add: do you exactly know why the droppable doesn't works ? is it a double event being triggered or something ?

Comment: Well, I only have limited knowledge of the sortable widget's inner workings, but my best guess would be that it is hardwired to revert the dragged element to its original position in the DOM when it is not dropped over a connected sortable. Even if the droppable widget handles the `drop` event and reparents the dragged element, it cannot prevent the sortable widget from undoing it afterwards. There's a way to be sure, though: `clone()` the dragged element in your `drop` handler and see if it sticks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not fully what i wanted, at the end Frederic's solution was the one i used and works. I can't imagine why using two sortables behave better than a sortable and a droppable for what i want.